# Service fabric on premises add node and node type correlation

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I have a 2 node on-premises windows cluster with the following node definitons in cluster manifest

```
 "nodes": [
  {
    "nodeName": "node1",
    "iPAddress": "192.168.1.1",
    "nodeTypeRef": "node1",
    "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r1",
    "upgradeDomain": "UD1"
  },
  {
    "nodeName": "node2",
    "iPAddress": "192.168.1.2",
    "nodeTypeRef": "node2",
    "faultDomain": "fd:/dc2/r2",
    "upgradeDomain": "UD2"
  }
```

I am trying to add a new node called "node3" using "AddNode.ps1" script:

```
 .\AddNode.ps1 -FabricRuntimePackagePath  "G:\Downloads\ServiceFabricRuntime\MicrosoftAzureServiceFabric.6.2.274.9494.cab" -NodeName node3 -NodeType "node3" -NodeIPAddressorFQDN 192.168.1.3 -ExistingClientConnectionEndpoint node0.gbl.net:19000 -UpgradeDomain UD3 -FaultDomain fd:/dc3/r3 -AcceptEULA
```

I get the error "Invalid Node Type" in powershell. Per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/add-servicefabricnode?view=azureservicefabricps), NodeType must be an *"existing"* nodetype in the cluster. I am wondering why is this? What does the "NodeTypeRef" signify in the clustermanifest.json? If I run AddNode.ps1 with nodetype param as "node1" or "node2" [which are existing nodetypes], it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can think of **NodeType** as of some abstract definition of hardware of executing environment where your services are going to be executed.

Consider an example:

Imagine you have two services A and B. Service A does lots of Disk I/O bound operations while Service B requires a lot of memory to work.

According to this information you can define two **NodeType's** then: *FastSDD* and *HugeMemory*. When adding Nodes to a cluster you specify appropriate NodeType based on the  hardware (i.e. machines with SSD as *FastSSD* and machines with huge RAM as *HugeMemory*).

Now you can define the following [placement constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#node-properties-and-placement-constraints) for your services:

- Service A: NodeType == FastSSD
- Service B: NodeType == HugeMemory

Using this configuration **ClusterManager** would organize your services in a way to ensure that replicas of *Service A are placed on Node's of type FastSSD* and *Service B are placed only on Node's of type HugeMemory*.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-nodetypes), each node type is mapped to a VMSS (Virtual Machine Scale Set). A VMSS is a collection of nodes with same configuration, so each node in the VMSS will have the same amount of RAM, CPU, OS, and configurations(Ports, Softwares, and so on), Unless you set individual configurations for each node after deployed.

> NodeType must be an "existing" nodetype in the cluster. I am wondering why is this? What does the "NodeTypeRef" signify in the clustermanifest.json?

On SF the NodeType is a virtual representation of a pool of nodes(VMs) with equal configurations that can handle the same type and amount of work as the others in same pool.

They are Virtual because they represent a pool of machines, it is not strictly tied to a VMSS, as you won't have VMSS when you run your cluster OnPremises or on other Cloud Providers, but you still can have a pool of virtual machines of same configurations linked to a NodeType.

Your cluster soon or later will have to scale(up and down) the number of nodes, having a NodeType will make it easier to place services on new nodes, because you know that specific NodeTypes have pre-defined requirements and any new node added to the pool will be compatible, so you don't need a complex configuration on your services configuration to restrict services running on nodes that are not supported.

Another example is, if you didn't have NodeType, and you need to assign a service to a specific node, in cases where the node goes offline, you service would not be able to run, as the Node is not available. Then you think, I could tie to specific requirements using labels in the nodes(i.e: Ram=8Gb) but in case you want to upgrade these VMs to have 16GB, you would have also to update the services, that now should be compatible with 16GB.

An example is a cluster like this:

***FrontEndNodetype***:
    You will install the services required to host your UI or APIs, won't need huge amounts of disk, you have to configure LoadBalancer ports to open access for example to port 80(http)

***BackEndNodeType***:
    Will host worker services that will handle heavy load, need more CPU and Memory.

***DBNodeType***:
    Will host your databases, need memory and Disk storage

Assuming you gonna restrict your APIs to run on the FrontEndNodetype, if you add a new node there to reduce the load on other nodes, SF will know that it will attend the service requirements and could run your API there without  any problems, because you already said during deployment that FrontEndNodetype contains all dependencies the service needs.

Another example could be a GPU based work, so your services would require a very specific hardware to run.

.

Based on your example:

If you create one nodetype for each node you add, you loose the benefit of having node types, and you would not have the same flexibility as described above.

The other issue is when you add multiple nodes with different configurations to the same nodetype, won't be an issue to service fabric, but soon or later your services will start failing on a specific node, maybe because the configuration is wrong or missing some dependencies, , will be hard to debug and find the problem as each node will have a different configuration, you will take take a while to identify that the problems only happens in that node

Comment: Diego, it seems like your answer was based on using Azure, but in this question the focus is on OnPremise, so in this case NodeType doesn't have anything to do with VMSS.  I've got the same problem, i'm trying to add a new node type to my cluster.  My first nodes were on the LAN and the new nodes I'm trying to add are in the DMZ.  But I can't add the new node type unless it exists.  So how do we add a new node type on Prem?  I see the Azure powershell has an add nodetype call but what about OnPremise?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.servicefabric/add-azurermservicefabricnodetype?view=azurermps-6.13.0&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-4.2.0

Comment: You are right, I shouldn't make my answer coupled to the VMSS, but the main point I tried to justify is `NodeType is a virtual representation of a pool of nodes(VMs) with equal configurations that can handle the same type and amount of work`, so no matter if it is on azure or On-Premisses, it should work the same way, the only difference is how you add extra NodeTypes to each.

Comment: I saw you already resolve your issue. In summary you have to update the cluster definition to add the NoteTypes and the Nodes. In azure the Resource Provider does that for you, OnPremises, is manual.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time on this last night and got past the node type error.  I'm now looking at a different error but that's a different story.  As stated above you need to add the node type to the existing cluster and then add the new node.  The other wrinkle we ran into for onPremise install is that you need to make a change to AddNode.ps1.  Here are the 3 steps:

1. Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade

```
    cd D:\TMHPSupport\Installs\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer.x.x.x
    Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "mycluster.mydomain.com:19000" -WindowsCredential
    Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade -ClusterConfigPath NewNodeType.ClusterConfig.Windows.MultiMachine.json
```

2. Update the addnode.ps1 to pass windows credentials - for some reason you need to adjust the addnode.ps1 to pass windows credentials if you are securing the cluster with windows credentials when it is connecting to the cluster.  So on line 203

```
    if($X509Credential)
    {    Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint $ExistingClientConnectionEndpoint -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint $ServerCertThumbprint -StoreLocation $StoreLocation -StoreName $StoreName -FindValue $FindValueThumbprint -FindType FindByThumbprint
    }
    else
    {
        Connect-ServiceFabricCluster $ExistingClientConnectionEndpoint **-WindowsCredential**
    }
```

3. Call AddNode.ps1

```
.\AddNode.ps1 -NodeName dmz1 -NodeType newNodeType -NodeIPAddressorFQDN newnodeservername.domain.org -ExistingClientConnectionEndpoint existingnodeservername.domain.org:19000 -UpgradeDomain UD3 -FaultDomain fd:/dc1/r1 -AcceptEULA
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-windows-server-add-remove-nodes#add-node-types-to-your-cluster  I did find this is documented as the correct approach and the issue with addnode.ps1 was fixed in 6.4 https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/974